# Kernel 5.3 in Ubuntu 19.10 (and other distros) blackscreens me

Tags: kernel, 19.10

A bit of history – I have two computers… my daily driver with Ryzen CPU and NVIDIA GPU, and my play/testing rig, which is just an Intel CPU with its own graphics (UHD 630) requiring i915 drivers. My play/testing rig has 8 HDDs and 2 SSDs. Each HDD has 4 partitions, one swap and three ‘distro’ partitions.

Ever since Linux kernel 5.3 came out and distros have been using it for ISOs, my play/testing rig has been pretty much useless. The 5.3 kernel simply blackscreens me as soon as the ISO loads. The daily driver Ryzen/NVIDIA system is totally fine with kernel 5.3.

There have only been two ways to get around kernel 5.3 for my play/testing rig. One is to use ‘nomodeset’ when I go through grub. This would actually allow me to install a new distro on one of my partitions, but it would be pointless anyway as I get blackscreened by kernel 5.3 in any case, although I could also install another kernel (if I can manage that). The other way is to upgrade via the actual distro itself and make sure I have another kernel present, so I can go in through Advanced mode and use that kernel to run the system.

In some Arch systems, I have used the 4.19 LTS kernel. In the recent Ubuntu updates, I installed the 5.2 kernel and upgraded rather than re-installed. Same with POP OS which let me use the 19.04 kernel which was kernel 5.0. With Fedora (Cinnamon and Deepin), I had to keep the 5.2 kernel active even after going to 5.3 because 5.3 simply doesn’t load. And I hope to upgrade using Fedora’s upgrade mechanism to Fedora 31 in a week or so.

Still, this is becoming somewhat frustrating for me. I actually don’t mind using ‘nomodeset’ to load and install, but clearly, I need to be able to somehow add i915 drivers in ‘after’ installation to actually get my new installs to work. And, I’m pretty much still a newbie, so I don’t know how to go about that.

Hence, I’m on here seeking advice. I’m also hoping that at some stage the new kernel won’t keep blackscreening me – it seems weird that my simple APU only system won’t work where my mish-mash of a Ryzen/NVIDIA system works fine with kernel 5.3. Any and all advice gratefully accepted.

Comment: Possible off-topic question. You've littered your question with more off-topic non-Ubuntu releases than any on-topic Ubuntu question. This site is for Ubuntu and official flavor of Ubuntu questions (Pop_OS is neither)  See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  When 19.10 released some firmware binaries weren't available, but are available post-install and appear on upgrade.... But your question would be better suited on SE's Unix & Linux as you're asking generic GNU/Linux and not limiting yourself to on-topic official Ubuntu.

Comment: I've done a heck of a lot of research already, asked other Linux users... and honestly thought this was about the only place I might get some kind of practical solution. I have to be honest, I can't understand why it isn't an issue that's cropped up already. Ubuntu is very popular and I've had this issue with all 5 of my direct Ubuntu partitions as well as POP. Are you referring to the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange? Happy to try there if that's your recommendation?

Comment: Yes SE's Unix & Linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/) supports all GNU/Linux & Unix (BSD etc) unlike this site which is an official Ubuntu linked site (*the use of the Canonical owned Ubuntu logo top left might be a clue!, let alone site rules*)

Comment: No worries... thanks for your support. I'll also go back in and re-install all the LTS versions of Ubuntu on those 5 partitions (and POP). Clearly, those variants won't give me this blackscreen issue!

Comment: FWIW, I found this question because I burned a day with kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10 and its broken i915 drivers, so it seems like a pretty relevant question to me

Comment: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111966 seems relevant

Comment: Thanks for the support, guys. I eventually managed to find out that it is only 'some' Intel CPUs that are impacted by kernel 5.3. There is a fix, but it doesn't come into play until kernel 5.3.8. I know that because I managed to get my Fedora drives and my Arch drives working with 5.3.8. I gave up with the Ubuntu and POP drives because it didn't seem like anyone was interested... I now have the LTS versions installed. Not sure if someone from the Ubuntu side of things can get that part fixed or not? I can probably find you the kernel commit if that is useful. Cheers.